# jQuery Ajax sucess function not working

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have this very simple login form with user and pass and I need to check that both are in a database and I'm using ajax for this:

```
$("#clientes").bind("submit", function() {
    $(".error_usu").hide();
    $.ajax({
        type        : "POST",
        cache       : false,
        url         : "login.php",
        data        : $(this).serializeArray(),
        success: function(data) {
            switch(data){
                case '1'://exito
                    alert("alert!");
                    window.location.href = "clientes.php";
                break;
                case '2'://pass
                    $(".error_pass").show();
                break;
            }
        }
    });

    return false;
});
```

inside login.php I have this:

```
 <? session_start();
 if(!empty($_POST['usuario']) && !empty($_POST['password']))
 {
include "funciones.php";
$username = $_POST['usuario'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];
$con=conectar();
$checklogin = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM clientes WHERE user = '".$username."' AND pass = '".$password."'",$con) or die (mysql_error());

if(mysql_num_rows($checklogin) == 1){
    $_SESSION['usuario'] = $_POST['usuario'];
    $_SESSION['password'] = $_POST['password'];
    echo '1';
}else{
    echo '2';
}

 }else{
     echo '2';
 }?>
```

When I check with firebug I see I'm getting a 1 or a 2 but de success function is never working! I tried this before I had the database just checking this way inside login.php and it worked:

```
if($_POST['usuario']=="fulano" && $_POST['password']=="fulano"){
    echo '1';
}
```

Is it not working because of the $_SESSION variables? I don't fully understand how ajax function works.

Comment: add into $.ajax call parameter dataType: 'html' and you will have it

Comment: Is your success function not being called, or not stepping into a case statement? Try `success: function(data) { alert(data); }`, just to check that the function is being called and that the data is as you expected (ie, doesn't include any whitespace, header information, html code, etc)

Comment: Connell is right, it's not going inside the switch, but firebug shows me the 1 or 2 :S I tried the datatype and it won't work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If it's not entering the switch statement you could multiply the response with 1, then JavaScript makes it a number instead of text.

```
success: function(data) {
        data *= 1;
        switch(data){
```

or

```
success: function(data) {
        data = parseInt(data);
        switch(data){
```

Comment: Ok this did the trick now I really want to know what the hell was happening here? why didn't the datatype work?

Comment: @Glenn85 : It is a good trick to know! But I think Elaine would find a way to handle it as an integer so that the next guy who will visit the code can find it more easy to understand. Don't you think so?

Comment: The response was in text format, but a switch statement only works with numbers. By the "data *= 1;" statement JavaScript handles the response as number.

Comment: Thanks to both of you for your help, it was driving me nuts.

Comment: @pencilCake If you mean this makes the code ugly then I agree with you, perhaps the following code looks a bit better: `data = parseInt(data)`. I placed the code in the answer as well.

Answer (score 2):

Did you try specifying the correct data-type you want to use?

For example:

```
   type:       "POST",
   dataType:   "text",
```

Just to be sure you can add:

```
error:      function(err){alert("Errror:"+err.toString());},
```

and see if it returns an error and if yes what is the error string.

Can you also try this, in case your success method is hit:

```
success: function(data) {alert(data==1); alert(data=='1'); }
```

Comment: Not working and no error message is showing. I only got an alert when I did what connell said.

Comment: Just to be sure, are you saying that the returned vaule is a string '1' or it is integer 1. Maybe that is the reason.

Comment: As you see in my question inside de login.php file I return echo '1'; and I try to catch that with the switch using switch(data){ case '1': ...} but that wasn't working for whatever reason. doing the data *= 1; trick made it work after changing the switch to case 1:

Answer (score 2):

You could try to capture the response by implementing the error handler in you ajax call. You could also try to set the dataType you're expecting to receive. It would look something like this:

```
en$.ajax({
    type        : "POST",
    cache       : false,
    url         : "login.php",
    data        : $(this).serializeArray(),
    dataType    : "text",
    error       : function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
         //Look at the values of jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown
    },
    success: function(data) {
        switch(data){
            case '1'://exito
                alert("alert!");
                window.location.href = "clientes.php";
            break;
            case '2'://pass
                $(".error_pass").show();
            break;
        }
    }
});
```